# mxnet: how to retrieve the number of example from the DataIter object?

Tags: mxnet

After using the mx.io.ImageRecordIter() to load my training examples, is there a way to retrieve the total number of examples from the returned DataIter object ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Sharing your code and using proper formatting of code in your quesrion increases chance for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Length of the iterator is unknown until you iterate through it.

You could iterate through and count the number of examples but depending on the data set size, this could be a time consuming operation.